# Trying to understand what "save_for_backward" is in Pytorch

Tags: python, class, pytorch

I have some knowledge in Pytorch,but i don't really understand the mechanisms of classes within Pytorch.
For example in the link: https://pytorch.org/tutorials/beginner/examples_autograd/two_layer_net_custom_function.html
you can find the following code:

```
import torch

class MyReLU(torch.autograd.Function):

    @staticmethod
    def forward(ctx, input):
        ctx.save_for_backward(input)
        return input.clamp(min=0)

    @staticmethod
    def backward(ctx, grad_output):       
        input, = ctx.saved_tensors
        grad_input = grad_output.clone()
        grad_input[input < 0] = 0
        return grad_input
```

i am only focusing on the forward method of this class,and i am wondering what

```
ctx.save_for_backward(input)
```

does.Whether the previous line of code is present or not is irrelevent when i try the forward method on a concrete example:

```
a=torch.eye(3)
rel=MyReLU()
print(rel.forward(rel,a))
```

as i get the same result in both cases.Could someone explain me what is happening and why it is useful to add the save_for_backward?
Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `ctx.save_for_backward` method is used to store values generated during `forward()` that will be needed later when performing `backward()`. The saved values can be accessed during `backward()` from the `ctx.saved_tensors` attribute.

Comment: thank you very much for your answer.I have one more question however: how are the methods save_for_backward and saved_tensors linked together?I don't find any code defining these methods on the Pytorch website.

Comment: what is the equivalent method save_for_backward() in tensorflow?